# C# Windows Forms GUI - Monitor Windows Startup

Tags: c#, service, startup

I have a C# Windows Forms interactive app and a related C# windows service.

On the particular machines where these are deployed, the login and app startup are automatic.  The interactive app always starts well before the service.  The app has a status indicator to show when it has connected to the service, but these machines are slow and it takes 45-60 seconds for my service to finally get started.  During this time, there is nothing happening on the screen.

I should point out that my service starts quickly... it's the dependent (and other) services that are taking some time to start.

I would like to have some sort of indication of the windows startup progress displayed while the application is waiting for the service.  I was thinking of showing a progress bar showing something like started_automatic_services/automatic_services.  Is there some other more appropriate method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use a [WMI event query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to monitor the services starting up, which would allow you at least to give an idea of progress

```
Starting services:  
Service 1 started 
Service 2 started etc.
```

The MSDN sample [Subscribing to and Consuming Management Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720671%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) should be enough to get you going, as it specifically illustrates querying services for state changes.

Comment: I've never used this... nice.

Comment: One caveat is that the WMI service must be started before querying WMI

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a tray icon? An image that represents a 'broken' or uninitialized connection to your service would be the initial one used, and once the service comes up you can change that to a 'normal' or 'all is well' icon. Some AV software clients do that.

You could also use the same icon with an overlay, maybe a small hourglass on the lower right corner or something like that, and then remove it.

Maybe showing a progress bar every single time the user boots could be rather intrusive and annoying.